# Android: Instantiating JNDI factory from reflection on Android forcing javax

Tags: android, reflection, jms, jndi, qpid

I'm trying to port:  Apache Qpid Client, JMS and JNDI -- to Android.  I'm able to get a successful compile/build of my QpidDroid project when running the ant debug install targets after passing Dalvik the --core-library parameter to allow javax packages for JMS/JNDI.  I'm hoping to do this before considering repackaging/refactoring javax classes into a different package namespace using jarjar.

I think this is legally legit because I'm using the old/first seperate JNDI jar currently provided by Oracle's website.  I'm using the JMS jar that comes with Apache Geronimo in Qpid,.. but I think it's also available from Oracle as a seperate download.  My dev environment uses Android platform 2.1 and jdk 1.6.

The problem is, it seems it currently cannot instantiate my custom jndi connection factory: PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory.  This is a .java source file in my QpidDroid project(not a .class in a libs jar)   (I extracted the class out of the qpidClient jar).

Would someone have any idea as to why it cannot be instantiated here?  I was wondering if proguard might be breaking reflection,... but I'm building it with the debug ant task,.. so I'm thinking proguard shouldn't be running at all.  The exception occurs when I run the installed app on the emulator.  I have the Apache Qpid service running on the same machine with the default port that it uses.

```
01-18 18:05:16.966: W/System.err(296): [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory]javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
01-18 18:05:17.006: W/System.err(296):  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getDefaultInitialContextFactory(NamingManager.java:720)
01-18 18:05:17.006: W/System.err(296):  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:768)
01-18 18:05:17.016: W/System.err(296):  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:169)
01-18 18:05:17.016: W/System.err(296):  at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:146)
01-18 18:05:17.016: W/System.err(296):  at org.rif.QpidDroid.Hello.runTest(Hello.java:56)
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem -- Android has bugs in it with Reflection prior to version 2.3

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6636

I ported my QpidDroid project to Android 2.3 and it looks like JNDI is successfully creating the InitialContext now with the QPID connection params